# `JAVA_HOME is not set and no java command could be found in your path` after installing Android studio in AWS Workspace (Windows)

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-workspaces

Need your help to solve `JAVA_HOME is not set and no java command could be found in your path` after installing Android studio in AWS Workspace (Windows). I can't edit environment variable as it requires admin credentials.

When I tried `java -version` in the terminal, it says `java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

But I believe Android Studio installs the required jdk/jre/jbr.

Comment: Recent Android Studio versions include their own JRE and JDK. These versions are not added to PATH, thus your `java -version` command fails.